# serializing file via R, for insertion as blob

Tags: r

I know there are at least a few reasons one might not want to do this, but I'm going to want to do it anyway. I want to take a lot of PDFs, store them as blobs (so nodes can read them from the main SQL server).

What would be the best practice for an R user to read the PDF content as a string, serialize it, and insert into MYSQL as a blob?

I assume all I really need is a text representation of the pdf which can then be BLOB'ed

Comment: [`git2r`](https://github.com/ropensci/git2r) has a `blob_create` function that might fit the bill.

Comment: Is it too forward to say I love you? Thanks, I will try this.

Comment: Ha! Hadley is also working on [a relevant package named `blob`](https://github.com/rstats-db/blob), though I'm not sure how complete it is.